# TFS Build definition argument in custom activity

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition

Got a build definition template, with custom argument 'NpmEnabled' (if i look at the xml of the xaml template, it is a part of the

```
<x:Members>
  <x:Property Name="NpmEnabled" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
</x:Members>
```

I can set the NpmEnable in my Build Definition.

Now i have a CustomActivity, and want to use this setting. How do I get this setting from the context?

The next code does not work...

```
[BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
[ActivityTracking(ActivityTrackingOption.ActivityOnly)]
public sealed class NpmInstall : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<string> NpmEnabled { get; set; }

    public override void Execute(CodeActivityContext contect)
    {
        string x = context.GetValue<string>(this.NpmEnabled);
    }
}
```

This way i need to set the NpmEnabled variable in the workflow template to a specific value, but i want the value of the setting I see in the build definition.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy: in your [custom template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx), you will refer to the assembly containing your custom activity at the beginning of the build template

`<Activity xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:MyCompany.TfsBuild.Activities;assembly=MyCompany.TfsBuild.Activities"`

and then invoke the activity like this

`<myns:NpmInstall NpmEnabled="[NpmEnabled]" />`

the square parenthesis introduce a VB expression.

Everything is done in the XAML.

Please, fix the incoherence in your code: the `NpmEnabled` variable is declared as **`Boolean`**, while the Activity property is of type **`string`**.